# Content of Jsp doesnt display at internal browser eclipse

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse, server, display

My page content doesn't display in internal browser of eclipse. Everytime I run this jsp code in eclipse, it only shows blank page instead the content of the page. I don't know what's wrong with my code. Please, help me. Here I attached my jsp code.

[image: Project explorer]

[jsp code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/13fOpiy7g3q5ch_0Ky8DPgy714BrcKyM5/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: On Windows, Linux or macOS? If on Windows, can you see the content externally in the Internet Explorer (might be an IE issue since on Windows Eclipse uses the IE by default)?

Comment: On windows. I try it in chrome, IE and even eclipse, it doesn't work at all. Everytime I run it display blank page only